# How to invert a linear hash function?

Tags: hash

My friend is trying to convince me that his linear hash function (with a few bit operations) is secure. Is there a way to disprove this? (Or prove this, but I've read from multiple sources that this kind of hash is very insecure).

Sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which of the [four main properties of a cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) does your friend claim their function has? The way to disprove their claim is to give them a counter example.

Comment: "it is infeasible to generate a message from its hash value". I can't seem to find a way to recreate it as the hash takes the value mod 2^32

Comment: So the output is only 32 bits? Should be able to generate a message that has the same hash value. Note it doesn't have to be the exact same message as the original. As long as they have the same hash value, you have found a pre-image. A collision would be easier to find, but with 32 bit outputs, even a pre-image should be brute-forceable.

Comment: Hint: write down (perhaps in the question) your definition of a _linear hash function_. Obtain $H(M_i)$ for all $M_i$ of some fixed size with exactly one bit set, and if that's not implied by your definition, the hash of the all-zero message with that fixed size. Show how you can constructively and efficiently compute a message $M$ of that fixed size with $H(M)=H(M′)$, given $H(M′)$, for any unknown $M′$ of that fixed size (we do not care if $M=M′$ or not). That achieves your goal.